# MySqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, база-данных, vb.net

Имеется форма с компонентами DataGridView1, BindingSource1, DataTable

Необходимо сохранить в базу все изменения сделанные в DataGridView1 (т. е. необходимо переопределить в адаптере методы Update и Delete). Пытаюсь делать примерно так:

```
Dim dataset = DataTable  
Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter()
Dim cn As New MySqlConnection(My.Settings.tickedoffConnectionString)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
                Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT `id`, `stay` FROM stay", cn)
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd
                    da.Fill(dataset)
                    Dim bs = BindingSource1
                    bs.DataSource = dataset
                    DataGridView1.DataSource = bs
                    da.Update(dataset)
                End Using

               ' теперь необходимо переопределить апдейт и делит
                     Dim updateCommand As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("UPDATE stay SET stay = @newValue WHERE `id` = @oldValue", cn)
                da.UpdateCommand = updateCommand

              Dim deleteCommand As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("DELETE FROM stay WHERE `id` = @oldValue", cn)
                da.DeleteCommand = deleteCommand

                ' и при необходимости будет использоваться примерно так: da.Update(dataset)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Как сделать что бы вместо @newValue подставлялось новое значение с грида для соответствующей записи (т.е. с Id @oldValue)

P.S. Я знаю, что параметры можно добавлять

```
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newValue", "new stay")
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldValue", "1")
```

но не знаю как их брать только для измененных полей
т.е. хочется написать что-то вроде

```
Dim deleteCommand As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("DELETE FROM stay WHERE `id` = @id", cn)
```

без явного указания значения идентификатора.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите [Обновление источников данных с объектами DataAdapter](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters).

Для вашей UpdateCommand:

```
"UPDATE stay SET stay = @newValue WHERE `id` = @oldValue"
```

нужно задать параметры:

```
var idParam = updateCommand.Parameters.Add("@oldValue", SqlDbType.Int); // укажите нужный тип
idParam.SourceColumn = "id";
idParam.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;

var stayParam = updateCommand.Parameters.Add("@newValue", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "stay"); // укажите нужный тип и колонку-источник (можно сделать это как в примере выше)
```

`DataAdapter` сам будет брать значения из изменённных строк и подставлять вместо параметров, в соответствии с именами колонок-источников (SourceColumn).

---

`var` - это C#. В VB, вероятно, будет `Dim`.

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую.